# From Swift object to json (formated [String: Any]) for alamofire REST post parameter (defined as [String: Any])

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

My purpose is to execute a REST post request via Alamofire.

I have an object:

```
struct Dog: Codable {
    var name: String
    var owner: String
}
```

I use this :

```
let JSONString = user.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true) //ObjectMapper call
```

returning :

```
{
    "name" : "Jon",
    "owner" : "Jon Doe"
}
```

But I want a `[String: Any]` structure, suitable for alamofire request like :

```
[
    "name" : "Jon",
    "owner" : "Jon Doe"
]
```

How to do that ?

Comment: You could call `let dict = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONString.data(using:.utf8), options:[])` (need to do a try/catch) but I guess there is more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Dog` is not correctly configured to use `ObjectMapper`, missing `Mappable` protocol.

```
struct Dog: Mappable  {
    var name: String?
    var owner: String?

    init?(map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        name    <- map["name"]
        owner   <- map["owner"]
    }
}
```

Then you can use `BaseMappable.toJSON` to pass to Alamofire's parameter, which is `[String: Any]`

```
let parameters: Parameters = user.toJSON()
_ = Alamofire.request(theURL, method:.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON() {
    // -----...
}
```

---

PS:
Your `user` mustn't be a `Dog` I guess? :P

Comment: It is configured but I did not put this mapping stuff for simplicifation reason.
Wow you solution seems to be very easy. This is what I was expecting by using ObjectMapper. I will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a property to your struct to  return a  dictionary representation, either complicated

```
var dictionaryRepresentation : [String : String] {
    return try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: try! JSONEncoder().encode(self)) as! [String : String]
}
```

or very simple

```
var dictionaryRepresentation : [String : String] {
    return ["name" : name, "owner" : owner]
}
```

---

Note:

Basically never send *prettyPrinted* strings to a server. It doesn't care at all about prettiness.

Comment: how to use than this property ?

dictionaryRepresentation = user.toJSONString(prettyPrint: true) ??

Comment: Put it in the struct and use it `let dog = Dog(name: "Pluto", owner: "Goofy")` `let dict = dog.dictionaryRepresentation`. Forget `toJSONString`